# what is the use of INITIAL_CAPACITY in this code

Tags: java

I am trying to do some stack functions, but I don't understand what's the use of INITIAL_CAPACITY. Can you help me please?

```
public class Stack<S> 
{   

  S[] elements; 
  int size;private static final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 100;

  public  Stack() 
  { elements = (S[]) new Object[INITIAL_CAPACITY];
  }
  public  Stack (int capacity)
  { elements = (S[]) new Object[capacity];}
```

Comment: This one's pretty self-documenting. You've got an array-backed stack, and it has an initial capacity...

Comment: Is this your first time using arrays?

Answer (score 0):

It sets the initial size of the object array. Basically a starting default value when using the no argument constructor. So basically it gives you the option to instantiate the object without passing in the capacity to the constructor.